# Вечно запущенный процесс

Tags: linux, ubuntu

В моем примере я пытаюсь отслеживать процесс, для того чтобы он был всегда запущен. Я делаю это через вечный цикл. И в целом это работает. Если сервер падает, он сразу же запускает его.

```
while true; do
      ./startServer.x86_64 -logfile 
done
```

Похоже, такой метод потребляет много ресурсов процессора. Помогите, пожалуйста, советом как можно улучшить.

Comment: если процесс возвращает управление в консоль только при своём завершении (а не делает форк и возвращает управление почти сразу) - то такой цикл ничего не потребляет.

Comment: @Мелкий Понял спасибо)